# How can I port StackOverflow to Portuguese?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, languages, translations

SO is very important for us here in Brazil, but many people can not use Stack Exchange sites because they do not know English language.

If SE would accept, I would be pleased to translate it to Portuguese, in a new site or in a translation mechanism.

Comment: Try using Google Chrome. When it loads a page that's not in your primary language, it asks you if you'd like Google to translate the page for you. :)

Comment: @animuson That's quite not a good solution, unless you want to "just have an idea of the subject being treated". :P

Comment: Google Chrome alone will note bring Brazilian programmers into the site. Google translation (every computer translation) is very low quality when converting English to other Latin language. :(

Comment: @EASI: Very low is quite an understatement.

Comment: @JohnSmith, see what I am telling you...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Theoretically, you could translate every question and answer we have so long as you provide [proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), but with over 3 million questions and 7 million answers (and more being posted every day), you'd have a hard time keeping up.

We have a site proposal for [Stack Overflow (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) in our Area 51 site where new Stack Exchange sites are proposed and gain a following before being created. I suggest committing to that proposal to show your support instead.

At this point it's too early to tell how viable it's going to be when launched, how we're going to go about it, or even when we'll be able to make it a site, but we are looking at localization issues and at how we can bring Stack Exchange in general and Stack Overflow in particular to more languages and countries, so the future is bright and full of promise. :)